# Canaries Setup [Write API]

Tags: automated-tests

We have a service that hosts an interface where users can upload files, and it uses EMR to conduct ETL and finally generates an output in S3. The entire process is handled in the backend by StateMachine and we also record the workflow statuses in DDB. The service also hosts few additional read/write apis.

We wanted to write canaries now. For Read APIs, its straigh-forward. What is the general guidance for the test the write APIs.

a) Should we be adding them in scope of canaries.

b) If yes, how to handle the DDB Record and EMR getting triggered every 5 mins(lets suppose we are running canaries every 5 mins) We can skip that part but is it advisable to do that in the main code like have if check for some canary condition.

c) Some people have suggested TTL but IMO, TTL will reduce the DB burden but other things would still be happening in the system and it would leave the system like some footprints present and some missing.

Above are just some points, I wanted to get more understanding on if someone has already brainstormed in this direction.